# Multi file upload in Ext.Net via asp.net

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, ext.net

I am using Ext.NET in VS2012. I want to use multiple file upload.(like [this](https://www.google.com.tr/search?biw=1252&bih=619&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=file%20upload&oq=file%20upload&gs_l=img.3..0j0i24l9.19977.22134.0.22248.11.7.0.4.4.0.182.860.1j6.7.0....0...1c.1.26.img..0.11.889.RrlOuFUh80I#facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=xI_Jetb7cSOrLM%3a;Kz4IQRUCQ3F0DM;http%253A%252F%252Fwww.webresourcesdepot.com%252Fwp-content%252Fuploads%252Fjquery-drag-drop-file-upload.gif;http%253A%252F%252Fwww.webresourcesdepot.com%252Fjquery-file-upload-plugin-with-drag-n-drop-support%252F;480;235) )

I found this page but I dont want [this](http://examples.ext.net/#/Form/FileUploadField/Basic/)

How can I succeed ?

Comment: Maybe this link help you. [Here](http://osmanvilli.blogspot.ch/2013/09/aspnetde-multi-file-upload.html)

Answer (score 0):

i have used uplodify in my project for muiltiple file upload at once.it's very easy to implement in asp.net.
check below like.i hope it will be useful for you

```
http://www.uploadify.com/demos/
```

Comment: Its very usefull and good visual but my boss want to me via Ext.NET.